# Instantiating Custom Adapter by passing Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call the `LazyAdapter` constructor for setting the `ListView`. And I always see a `red line` on `new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);` asking to resolve this. I am not sure what should I add here in place of this, so that it can start working. When I try to replace this with `getApplicationContext` then I always get error as `ClassCastException`. Any thoughts what I need to add inplace of `this`?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> response) {

    if (response!=null) {
           adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

for(User user : response){
 //Doing Some Stuff Here    

}

}
```

And `LazyAdapter` constructor is something like this-

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }
```

**Update:-**

My LazyAdapter full code-

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured that out, I need replace this with `Class_activity_name.this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing the `Adapter` inside an `AsyncTask` method, so at the initialization time `this` points to `AsyncTask` instance. If the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of an `Activity`, then you can simply change `this` to `Activity.this`, otherwise you need to pass an `Activity` to the `AsyncTask` constructor and use it to initialize your `Adapter`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `this` variable is not being recognized by the editor. Try using `getBaseContext()`.

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(getBaseContext(), mStrings);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have already tried using the above thing. Whenever I try with `getBaseContext()`, I always get like `The constructor LazyAdapter(Context, String[]) is undefined`. In my question, I have already provided the LazyAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the AsyncTask, create a Constructor of AsyncTask and pass your activity reference(this) to `AsyncTask` like this:

```
AsyncTaskClass obj = AsyncTaskClass(this);
```

Constructor:

```
public AsyncTaskClass(Context context) {
          mContext = context;
}
```

And use this constructor in the `onPostExecute()` of your AsynTask.